# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de mencionar un año?(de o del)

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Institucionalmente utilizo `de` para referirme a un año. *Ejemplo:*

> 26 de Enero de 2012

Sin embargo, intuitivamente, estoy impulsado a utilizar `del` en otros contextos. *Ejemplo:*

> 26 de Enero del 2012

¿Cuál es la forma correcta?

Comment: Buena pregunta!

Comment: Muy buena realmente

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Antes del 2000 era común usar el artículo en fechas del 2000 en adelante. Sin embargo, después del 2000, por alguna razón (¿software de los diarios?) se dejó de hacerlo.

**Ambas formas son correctas.**

Incluso la RAE está de acuerdo, en el DPD, [artículo “Fecha”, sección 4](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=fecha#4).

> [...] se recomienda mantener este uso [(sin artículo)] en la datación de cartas y documentos del año 2000 y sucesivos: *4 de marzo de 2000*. Esta recomendación no implica que se considere incorrecto, en estos casos, el uso del artículo: *4 de marzo del 2000*.